# the second position absolute wrapper does not behave as first

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have prepared a css, where the same styles in one case work as expected, while further, nested navigation no longer.

My goal is to make show navigation right under the dropdown.

The application is used to bootstrap 4, but nevertheless the navigation is very custom

`.nav-center-nested` is used with the `first nested nav` and with the `second nested nav` - but with the second the same `style` (with the same `html`) work diferent

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    const toggleSpeed = 50, toggleFade = "slow";

    $('div[data-v]').on('click', function (event) {
        if ($(event.target).prop('tagName') !== 'A') {
            var that = this,
                nav = $('#main-nav'),
                absoluteWrapper = nav.find('div[data-w="' + $(that).data('v') + '"]'),
                allAbsoluteWrappers = nav.find('div[data-w]'),
                list = {};

            if (!$(that).attr('was')) {
                if ($(that).attr('name') == 'main-nav') {
                    nav.find('div[data-p]').each(function () { var that = this; $(that).hide(); });
                    nav.find('div[name="main-nav"]').each(function () { var that = this; $(that).removeAttr('was'); });
                    $(that).attr('was', 'here');

                    if (absoluteWrapper.length != 0) {
                        allAbsoluteWrappers.removeClass('py-3');
                        absoluteWrapper.addClass('py-3');
                    } else {
                        allAbsoluteWrappers.removeClass('py-3');
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $(that).removeAttr('was');
                allAbsoluteWrappers.removeClass('py-3');
            }

            if ($(that).children('[id="nav-btn-childrens-' + $(that).data('v') + '"]').length != 0) {
                list = nav.find('div[id="nav-nested-childrens-' + $(that).data('v') + '"]').children();
            } else {
                list = nav.find('div[data-p=' + $(that).data('v') + ']');
            }

            if (list != 'undefined' || list != null || list.length != 0) {
                list.each(function () {
                    var that = this;
                    if ($(that).css('display') == "none") { // || $(that).attr('name', 'nav-dropdown')
                        $(that).show(toggleSpeed, function () { $(that).fadeIn(toggleFade); });
                        //if ($(that).attr('name', 'nav-dropdown')) {
                        //    $(that).css('display', 'inline')
                        //}
                    } else {
                        $(that).hide(toggleSpeed, function () { $(that).fadeOut(toggleFade); });
                        nav.find('div[id="nav-nested-childrens-' + $(that).data('v') + '"]').children().each(function () {
                            var that = this;
                            $(that).hide(toggleSpeed, function () { $(that).fadeOut(toggleFade); });
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#main-nav a {
    z-index: 1000;
}

.logo-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 95%;
    width: 75px;
    z-index: 999;
}
.nav-center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.nav-center-nested {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    z-index: 998;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-btn-clear {
    border-width: 0;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-image: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

.nav-margin {
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
}

.nav-padding {
    padding-left: 25%;
    padding-right: 25%;
}

.nav-btn:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4); 
}
.nav-btn-margin {
    margin-top: -1rem;
    margin-bottom: -1rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.nav-btn-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-btn-right {
    text-align: right;
}

.nav-btn-left {
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 50px;
}

.kuguar-sport-color {
    background-color: rgba(227, 30, 36, 1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="categories" class="col kuguar-sport-color no-padding no-margin">
<nav id="main-nav">
    <div class="row nav-margin p-3 text-center"><div name="main-nav" class="col nav-btn nav-btn-margin" data-v="138"><button class="nav-btn-clear text-light"> Aktualności</button></div><div name="main-nav" class="col nav-btn nav-btn-margin" data-v="139"><button class="nav-btn-clear text-light"> O nas</button></div><div name="main-nav" class="col nav-btn nav-btn-margin" data-v="140"><button class="nav-btn-clear text-light"> Rowery</button></div></div><div class="position-relative"><div data-w="139" name="nav-first" class="nav-center-nested row no-margin nav-padding text-center kuguar-sport-color"><div style="display: none;" class="nav-btn nav-btn-margin col" data-p="139" data-v="376"><a class="text-light" href="#"> o nas1</a><button id="nav-btn-childrens-376" class="nav-btn-clear text-light"><i style="color: white;" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div><div class="position-relative"><div id="nav-nested-childrens-376" class="nav-center-nested row text-center"><div style="display: none;" class="col nav-btn nav-btn nav-btn-margin" data-p="376" data-v="379"><a class="text-light" href="#"> o nas11</a></div><div style="display: none;" class="col nav-btn nav-btn nav-btn-margin" data-p="376" data-v="380"><a class="text-light" href="#"> o nas12</a></div></div></div><div style="display: none;" class="nav-btn nav-btn-margin col" data-p="139" data-v="377"><a class="text-light" href="#"> o nas2</a></div><div style="display: none;" class="nav-btn nav-btn-margin col" data-p="139" data-v="378"><a class="text-light" href="#"> o nas3</a></div></div></div><div class="position-relative"><div data-w="140" name="nav-first" class="nav-center-nested row no-margin nav-padding text-center kuguar-sport-color"><div style="display: none;" class="nav-btn nav-btn-margin col" data-p="140" data-v="368"><a class="text-light" href="#"> Górskie</a><button id="nav-btn-childrens-368" class="nav-btn-clear text-light"><i style="color: white;" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div><div class="position-relative"><div id="nav-nested-childrens-368" class="nav-center-nested row text-center"><div style="display: none;" class="col nav-btn nav-btn nav-btn-margin" data-p="368" data-v="371"><a class="text-light" href="#"> testgorskie</a></div><div style="display: none;" class="col nav-btn nav-btn nav-btn-margin" data-p="371" data-v="372"><a class="text-light" href="#"> testgorskie2</a></div><div style="display: none;" class="col nav-btn nav-btn nav-btn-margin" data-p="372" data-v="373"><a class="text-light" href="#"> testgorskie3</a></div><div style="display: none;" class="col nav-btn nav-btn nav-btn-margin" data-p="368" data-v="374"><a class="text-light" href="#"> testgorskie1-1</a></div><div style="display: none;" class="col nav-btn nav-btn nav-btn-margin" data-p="368" data-v="375"><a class="text-light" href="#"> testgorskie1-2</a></div></div></div><div style="display: none;" class="nav-btn nav-btn-margin col" data-p="140" data-v="369"><a class="text-light" href="#"> Miejskie</a></div><div style="display: none;" class="nav-btn nav-btn-margin col" data-p="140" data-v="370"><a class="text-light" href="#"> Dziecięce</a><button id="nav-btn-childrens-370" class="nav-btn-clear text-light"><i style="color: white;" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div><div class="position-relative"><div id="nav-nested-childrens-370" class="nav-center-nested row text-center"><div style="display: none;" class="col nav-btn nav-btn nav-btn-margin" data-p="370" data-v="381"><a class="text-light" href="#"> Dziecięce1</a></div><div style="display: none;" class="col nav-btn nav-btn nav-btn-margin" data-p="370" data-v="382"><a class="text-light" href="#"> Dziecięce2</a></div><div style="display: none;" class="col nav-btn nav-btn nav-btn-margin" data-p="382" data-v="383"><a class="text-light" href="#"> Dziecięce21</a></div></div></div></div></div>
</nav>


</div>
```

**Question**
How to move nested nav from right to bottom of dropdown + when I adding `kuguar-sport-color` to nested nav - color dosent work

*Thanks!*

**EDIT**
[image: AIM]

Comment: can you share one screenshot with your expected output?

Comment: of course, please

Comment: the background color `kuguar-sport-color` for nested nav?

Comment: yes - `kuguar-sport-color`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have moved the nested sub menu into inside the `nav-btn-margin` to relative position. Also added `inner-dropdown` class for sub menu.

Try this solution and comment for further assistance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    const toggleSpeed = 50,
        toggleFade = "slow";

    $('div[data-v]').on('click', function(event) {
        if ($(event.target).prop('tagName') !== 'A') {
            var that = this,
                nav = $('#main-nav'),
                absoluteWrapper = nav.find('div[data-w="' + $(that).data('v') + '"]'),
                allAbsoluteWrappers = nav.find('div[data-w]'),
                list = {};

            if (!$(that).attr('was')) {
                if ($(that).attr('name') == 'main-nav') {
                    nav.find('div[data-p]').each(function() {
                        var that = this;
                        $(that).hide();
                    });
                    nav.find('div[name="main-nav"]').each(function() {
                        var that = this;
                        $(that).removeAttr('was');
                    });
                    $(that).attr('was', 'here');

                    if (absoluteWrapper.length != 0) {
                        allAbsoluteWrappers.removeClass('py-3');
                        absoluteWrapper.addClass('py-3');
                    } else {
                        allAbsoluteWrappers.removeClass('py-3');
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $(that).removeAttr('was');
                allAbsoluteWrappers.removeClass('py-3');
            }

            if ($(that).children('[id="nav-btn-childrens-' + $(that).data('v') + '"]').length != 0) {
                list = nav.find('div[id="nav-nested-childrens-' + $(that).data('v') + '"]').children();
            } else {
                list = nav.find('div[data-p=' + $(that).data('v') + ']');
            }

            if (list != 'undefined' || list != null || list.length != 0) {
                list.each(function() {
                    var that = this;
                    if ($(that).css('display') == "none") { // || $(that).attr('name', 'nav-dropdown')
                        $(that).show(toggleSpeed, function() {
                            $(that).fadeIn(toggleFade);
                        });
                        //if ($(that).attr('name', 'nav-dropdown')) {
                        //    $(that).css('display', 'inline')
                        //}
                    } else {
                        $(that).hide(toggleSpeed, function() {
                            $(that).fadeOut(toggleFade);
                        });
                        nav.find('div[id="nav-nested-childrens-' + $(that).data('v') + '"]').children().each(function() {
                            var that = this;
                            $(that).hide(toggleSpeed, function() {
                                $(that).fadeOut(toggleFade);
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#main-nav a {
    z-index: 1000;
}

.logo-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 95%;
    width: 75px;
    z-index: 999;
}

.nav-center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.nav-center-nested {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    z-index: 998;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-btn-clear {
    border-width: 0;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-image: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

.nav-margin {
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
}

.nav-padding {
    padding-left: 25%;
    padding-right: 25%;
}

.nav-btn:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.nav-btn-margin {
    margin-top: -1rem;
    margin-bottom: -1rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.nav-btn-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-btn-right {
    text-align: right;
}

.nav-btn-left {
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 50px;
}

.kuguar-sport-color {
    background-color: rgba(227, 30, 36, 1);
}

.inner-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 0;
    background: #e31e24;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 180px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    right: 0;
}

.inner-dropdown a {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="categories" class="col kuguar-sport-color no-padding no-margin">
    <nav id="main-nav">
        <div class="row nav-margin p-3 text-center">
            <div name="main-nav" class="col nav-btn nav-btn-margin" data-v="138">
                <button class="nav-btn-clear text-light"> Aktualności</button>
            </div>
            <div name="main-nav" class="col nav-btn nav-btn-margin" data-v="139">
                <button class="nav-btn-clear text-light"> O nas</button>
            </div>
            <div name="main-nav" class="col nav-btn nav-btn-margin" data-v="140">
                <button class="nav-btn-clear text-light"> Rowery</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="position-relative">
            <div data-w="139" name="nav-first" class="nav-center-nested row no-margin nav-padding text-center kuguar-sport-color">
                <div style="display: none;" class="nav-btn nav-btn-margin col position-relative" data-p="139" data-v="376"><a class="text-light" href="#"> o nas1</a>
                    <button id="nav-btn-childrens-376" class="nav-btn-clear text-light"><i style="color: white;" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    <div id="nav-nested-childrens-376" class="text-left inner-dropdown">
                        <div style="display: none;" class="" data-p="376" data-v="379"><a class="text-light" href="#"> o nas11</a></div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="" data-p="376" data-v="380"><a class="text-light" href="#"> o nas12</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="display: none;" class="nav-btn nav-btn-margin col position-relative" data-p="139" data-v="377"><a class="text-light" href="#"> Górskie</a>
                    <button id="nav-btn-childrens-377" class="nav-btn-clear text-light"><i style="color: white;" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    <div id="nav-nested-childrens-377" class="inner-dropdown text-left">
                        <div style="display: none;" class="" data-p="377" data-v="371"><a class="text-light" href="#"> testgorskie</a></div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="" data-p="377" data-v="372"><a class="text-light" href="#"> testgorskie2</a></div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="" data-p="377" data-v="373"><a class="text-light" href="#"> testgorskie3</a></div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="" data-p="377" data-v="374"><a class="text-light" href="#"> testgorskie1-1</a></div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="" data-p="377" data-v="375"><a class="text-light" href="#"> testgorskie1-2</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="display: none;" class="nav-btn nav-btn-margin col position-relative" data-p="139" data-v="378"><a class="text-light" href="#"> Dziecięce</a>
                    <button id="nav-btn-childrens-378" class="nav-btn-clear text-light"><i style="color: white;" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    <div id="nav-nested-childrens-378" class="inner-dropdown text-left">
                        <div style="display: none;" class="" data-p="378" data-v="381"><a class="text-light" href="#"> Dziecięce1</a></div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="" data-p="378" data-v="382"><a class="text-light" href="#"> Dziecięce2</a></div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="" data-p="378" data-v="383"><a class="text-light" href="#"> Dziecięce21</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm trying to implement it, but I can't change the html that is dynamically generated. The formula you added has a different hierarhie html. After all, this example show me the way of approche.

Comment: Without changing the html its bit complicated to align sub menu. Even class also dynamic?

Comment: unfortunately, yes, I am not a front-end dev and I was given the task to generate navigation and add styles. I took it badly because at first  I generated the code for bootstrap (I dont know this framework quite well) and I thought that it would be easy to add some css later.

Now I know that was a bad idea - in te future I have to make a template in the first place and then code behind for it.

in any case your answer helped me - really. I didnt use it 1:1 but it was helpfully.